# Azure Function App- Call One function by another function with dll

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Function1 dll is called into Function2. But if we made a change in Function1, have to replace that new dll of Function1 in Function2. And republish Function2.
Please suggest a solution for using refreshed dll in function2 without rebuild every time.

Comment: If you want to use the updated dll I don't see any option.

Comment: @PeterBons is there any other way for Function invoke and reduce multiple build attempt?

Comment: @Ujstest you can't just reduce build attempt. If you need dependency from function 2, or you are making too much changes a lot of times see if you can build it as class library and share it between two functions