# Azure Function App- Call functionA by functionB with dll

Tags: c#, azure, dll, azure-functions

1. FunctionA dll is called into FunctionB.If we made a change in functionA, then what steps I have to follow to reflect those changes into FunctionB.
2. Is the same process possible by Project reference?
3. Is Function A republish is enough to get changes in FunctionB?
4. What is the difference between Project reference and dll reference in the function app?

Please give your valuable guidance on the above points.

I have tried by project reference and republishing FunctionA after changes. This is not working.

Comment: Do the functions live in the same project or are they deployed separately?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Function App- Call One function by another function with dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800701/azure-function-app-call-one-function-by-another-function-with-dll)

Comment: @PeterBons Published separately on azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FunctionA dll is called into FunctionB.If we made a change in
> functionA, then what steps I have to follow to reflect those changes
> into FunctionB.

I suggest you to put the two function in one function app, if you publish them separately on azure, they will be no relationship.

> Is the same process possible by Project reference?

.dll reference is basically the same as project reference.

> Is Function A republish is enough to get changes in FunctionB?

Since you published separately on azure, then no matter you use project reference or .dll reference, there will be no relationship between them.

> What is the difference between Project reference and dll reference in
> the function app?

In fact, there is basically no differences. Even you use project reference, it will still compiled to .dll files.